# why does cassandra sometimes take a hours to start?

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra, database-performance, cassandra-3.0

I am running a 26 node cluster in ec2, spread across 4 regions - us-east-1, us-west-2, eu-west-1, and ap-southeast-1. I've noticed that sometimes nodes take a very long time to start up and the problem seems particularly bad in ap-southeast-1. For example, simply restarting a node today took over 4 hours. When this happens, the last thing logged by cassandra (system.log) is:

```
INFO  [main] 2016-10-19 20:35:14,846 ColumnFamilyStore.java:395 - Initializing system_schema.indexes
```

Eventually it moves on to initializing my own column families, but I don't understand what is taking so long. This particular node has about 900G of data on it, using a 3.2T EBS volume.

While this is happening there seems to be very little resource contention. Network i/o doesn't seem to go above 1Mb/s. Both the data volume and commit log have basically 0 i/o. CPU usage is in 25%-50% range. Looking at `strace`, there seems to be tons of `getdents` system calls, but that doesn't seem like it would be causing problems.

What could explain such a long startup time?

## Cluster Info

- Cassandra DDC 3.5
- EC2MultiRegionSnitch
- m4.xlarge, moving to c4.4xlarge

## Schema Info

- 3 CF's, all 'write once' (ie no updates), 1 week ttl, STCS (default)
- no secondary indexes

Comment: Are you using secondary indices?

Comment: It might be spending time replaying your commit log, but that shouldn't take an hour.  I *have* noticed that some versions of 3.x have issues where the commit log can become corrupted, but that usually prevents the node from starting and quickly fails.  Can you upgrade to 3.9, and see if you have the same issue?

Comment: Updated question with some schema info (there are no secondary indexes). I can try upgrading to 3.9, but the issue doesn't come up every time, so it might take some time to be able to say that resolves it. Is it safe to run a single 3.9 node with ~25 other nodes still on 3.5?

Comment: Upgrading to 3.9 does not seem to have resolved the issue

Comment: Depending on # of sstables, it may be something like https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-12114 (which I fixed recently), or https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11163 (which has not yet been built).